# Xcode 8.2.1, how to remove disconnected view controller completely from storyboard?

Tags: storyboard, xcode8, viewcontroller

I want to completely remove/delete a view controller from the storyboard that I'm not using. It's an extra view controller that I don't need. Is there a way to completely remove/delete an unused view controller from storyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to completely remove/delete an unused view controller from storyboard?

**Yes:**

1. Open the storyboard
2. Select the view controller that you don't need
3. Press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

There's also the Edit->Delete menu command, which does the same thing as pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I just drag all items into recycle bin and you can't with storyboard.